# Merge multiple backups of the same table schema into 1 master table

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I have about 200 copies of a SQLite database. All taken at different times with different data in them. Some rows are deleted and some are added. They are all in a single directory.

I want to merge all the rows in the table `my_table`, using all the `.db` files in the directory. I want duplicate rows to be deleted, showing all entires from all the databases, just once.

I'd like to do this in pure SQL, but I don't think it's possible, so we can use Python too.

Table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
    ROWID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    guid TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    text TEXT,
    replace INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
    service_center TEXT,
    handle_id INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
    subject TEXT,
    country TEXT,
    attributedBody BLOB,
    version INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
    type INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
    service TEXT,
    account TEXT,
    account_guid TEXT,
    error INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
    date INTEGER,
    date_read INTEGER,
    date_delivered INTEGER,
    is_delivered INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
    is_finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
    is_emote INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
    is_from_me INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
    is_empty INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
    is_delayed INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
    is_auto_reply INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
    is_prepared INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
    is_read INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
    is_system_message INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
    is_sent INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
    has_dd_results INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
    is_service_message INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
    is_forward INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
    was_downgraded INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
    is_archive INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
    cache_has_attachments INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
    cache_roomnames TEXT,
    was_data_detected INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
    was_deduplicated INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
    is_audio_message INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
    is_played INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
    date_played INTEGER,
    item_type INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
    other_handle INTEGER DEFAULT -1,
    group_title TEXT,
    group_action_type INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
    share_status INTEGER,
    share_direction INTEGER,
    is_expirable INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
    expire_state INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
    message_action_type INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
    message_source INTEGER DEFAULT 0
)
```

Comment: Show the table definition.

Comment: @CL. added to the above.

Comment: How are entries identified? By `rowid` or by `guid`?

Comment: @CL. by rowid, it is an integer count, and it's the primary key

Answer (score 7):

To be able to access both the master database and a snapshot at the same time, use [ATTACH](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html).
To delete and old version of a row, use [INSERT OR REPLACE](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html):

```sql
ATTACH 'snapshot123.db' AS snapshot;
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO main.my_table SELECT * FROM snapshot.my_table;
DETACH snapshot;
```

Do this with all databases, in order from oldest to newest.
(SQLite has no loop control mechanism for this; do this loop in Python.)

Alternatively, you can go backwards, from newest and oldest, and insert only rows that do not yet exist:

```sql
ATTACH 'snapshot123.db' AS snapshot;
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO main.my_table SELECT * FROM snapshot.my_table;
DETACH snapshot;
```

Comment: There are hundreds of databases, so it cannot really be done manually like this.

Comment: Although incomplete and a little rough (not deleting rows for instance) this is a very good start. Write a python script to automate this, add a delete query for the deleted rows... and you are pretty much ready to go.

Comment: @FlipVernooij According to the question, deleted rows should be kept. If deleted rows were to be hidden, the last snapshot would already contain exactly the wanted data.

Comment: @CL k, then the example is even better ;)

Comment: Can you convert this into Python? Mostly just wondering if I need 2 database connections.

Answer (score 1):

```
import sqlite3
conn_1 = sqlite3.connect('master.db')
c = conn_1.cursor()
import glob, os
os.chdir("/Users/me/Downloads/Archives")
for file in glob.glob("*.db"):
    if file != "master.db":
        print file
        conn_2 = sqlite3.connect(file)
            c2 = conn_2.cursor()
            query = "ATTACH '%s' AS snapshot;" % file
            query += "INSERT OR IGNORE INTO master.my_table SELECT * FROM snapshot.my_table;"
            query += "DETACH snapshot;"
            c.executescript(query)
```

Error: `sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: master.my_table`

Comment: The main database (the one opened without `ATTACH`) is always called `main`.

Answer (score 1):

two things:

you need to have my_table in your master.db

it should be my_table NOT master.my_table in your query.

```
import sqlite3
conn_1 = sqlite3.connect('master.db')
c = conn_1.cursor()

query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_table (ROWID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, guid TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL, text TEXT, replace INTEGER DEFAULT 0, service_center TEXT, handle_id INTEGER DEFAULT 0, subject TEXT, country TEXT, attributedBody BLOB, version INTEGER DEFAULT 0, type INTEGER DEFAULT 0, service TEXT, account TEXT, account_guid TEXT, error INTEGER DEFAULT 0, date INTEGER, date_read INTEGER, date_delivered INTEGER, is_delivered INTEGER DEFAULT 0, is_finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0, is_emote INTEGER DEFAULT 0, is_from_me INTEGER DEFAULT 0, is_empty INTEGER DEFAULT 0, is_delayed INTEGER DEFAULT 0, is_auto_reply INTEGER DEFAULT 0, is_prepared INTEGER DEFAULT 0, is_read INTEGER DEFAULT 0, is_system_message INTEGER DEFAULT 0, is_sent INTEGER DEFAULT 0, has_dd_results INTEGER DEFAULT 0, is_service_message INTEGER DEFAULT 0, is_forward INTEGER DEFAULT 0, was_downgraded INTEGER DEFAULT 0, is_archive INTEGER DEFAULT 0, cache_has_attachments INTEGER DEFAULT 0, cache_roomnames TEXT, was_data_detected INTEGER DEFAULT 0, was_deduplicated INTEGER DEFAULT 0, is_audio_message INTEGER DEFAULT 0, is_played INTEGER DEFAULT 0, date_played INTEGER, item_type INTEGER DEFAULT 0, other_handle INTEGER DEFAULT -1, group_title TEXT, group_action_type INTEGER DEFAULT 0, share_status INTEGER, share_direction INTEGER, is_expirable INTEGER DEFAULT 0, expire_state INTEGER DEFAULT 0, message_action_type INTEGER DEFAULT 0, message_source INTEGER DEFAULT 0)"

c.executescript(query)

import glob, os
os.chdir("/Users/me/Downloads/Archives")
for file in glob.glob("*.db"):
    if file != "master.db":
        print file
        conn_2 = sqlite3.connect(file)
        c2 = conn_2.cursor()
        query = "ATTACH '%s' AS snapshot;" % file
        query += "INSERT OR IGNORE INTO my_table SELECT * FROM snapshot.my_table;"
        query += "DETACH snapshot;"
        c.executescript(query)
```

Comment: On another machine, I get `sqlite3.DatabaseError: file is encrypted or is not a database`

Comment: It ran perfect with the same data and same script on another machine